# LinkedIn sharing is not showing the description

Tags: linkedin-api, sharing

I have Managed all the `OG` tag properly like following, and while sharing in LinkedIn, it shows title and image properly but it doesn't show the description. I have also used the inspector https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/ to check and it doesn't show anything error. Does LinkedIn recently remove the description showing?

My URL is : https://www.digitalcareerfest.com/job/british-american-tobacco-gbs-selangor-permanent-sourcing-specialist-procurement/

Let me know if I have made anything wrong on it as I have followed all criteria.

```html
<meta  property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta  property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="Sourcing Specialist (Procurement) &#8209; Talentbank Digital Career Festival" />
<meta name="description" property="og:description" content="Principle Accountabilities Responsible for the execution of sourcing activities for End markets and for the central Procurement teams To develop the processes, templates, governance and framework for executing eRFx processes and supporting other sourcing activities as necessary To manage the cadence and pipeline for eRFx including e-Auction activities and ensure appropriate support is provided to &hellip;" />
<meta  property="og:url" content="https://www.digitalcareerfest.com/job/british-american-tobacco-gbs-selangor-permanent-sourcing-specialist-procurement/" />
<meta  property="og:site_name" content="Talentbank Digital Career Festival" />
<meta  property="article:published_time" content="2020-04-30T03:50:25+00:00" />
<meta name="image" property="og:image" content="https://www.digitalcareerfest.com/wp-content/themes/workup/images/digital-career-banner.jpg" />
<meta name="image" property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.digitalcareerfest.com/wp-content/themes/workup/images/digital-career-banner.jpg" />
<meta name="image" property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta name="image" property="og:image:height" content="627" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Only one of the following levels may apply in the LinkedIn share preview...

- **Level 1:** Show the primary domain, title and ***image***.

  - **Applies if:** You supply ***an image***.
- **Level 2:** Show the primary domain, title and ***description***.

  - **Applies if:** You have ***no image*** and you supply a description.

I have gleaned this from talking with LinkedIn support for two weeks (*[Oh the humanity.](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*)

Example: Wikipedia ***uses description-only***, but GitHub ***uses image and description***.  How do they appear?

[image]
[image]

**Wikipedia:** [No `og:image` tag, but `og:description` displays.](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
**GitHub:** [Yes `og:image` tag, but no `og:description` displays.](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

And I made a working demo, as well, if you'd like a page without `og:image` tags (a rarity these days, surprisingly!).

[**Working LinkedIn Share Link Demo Without `og:image` Tags**](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html):

```
<HTML><HEAD>
    <meta property="og:title" content="LinkedIn Share URL Test">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Testing description!">
    <meta property='og:url' content="https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html"/>
</HEAD><BODY>This page has no og:image tag.</BODY></HTML>
```

I'm aware this disagrees with the [Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).  But reality appears to differ from what LinkedIn is telling us.